# multiple queries with multiple threads and multiple connections

Tags: python, multithreading, postgresql

I have a very large database of 10 million rows and for that i have a single server so i have decided to split the big table of 10 million row into 4 parts and perform search (select) operation on the tables . I would like to connect each of the tables using separate postgres connection and also each of the tables would have different names. I know python has multiprocessing module but i am not sure how to run the threads for each separate connection and for each query. I was looking into this code at http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=25722 but it does not allow show to run different multiple queries any help on this

Comment: You'd use the same pattern as pretty much any other multiprocess or multithreaded piece of code out there.

Comment: Without further reasoning it sounds like a __very__ poor idea

Comment: Your database queries are likely io bound, unless your storage is ssd based. Multi treading will likely just cause disk thrashing.

Comment: 10 million rows really isn't a very big table, generally speaking. It would be unusual for partitioning to be truly necessary at that threshold, unless perhaps you are doing enormously complicated queries (that, say, generate cartesian products), or each row contains a mammoth amount of data within the columns.

Comment: Take a step back. You're trying to solve a performance problem, presumably. You're attempting to do so by adding concurrency in the form of multiple threads. OK... what evidence do you have that that might help? Have you identified the current performance bottlenecks? Have you tried to determine what's taking the time at the moment? If you haven't, then trying to solve the problem is premature because *you don't really know what it is yet*.

Comment: Well i am doing chemical structure similarity search on a database for which it actually uses c++ and plsql to compute the jaccard similarity and present the results. I want the results in milliseconds time so i thought of this idea. So I thought to partition the table and run queries on each separate table and at the end join the results.I might be wrong of the idea as i am not a parallelism guy sorry about that. Well i have 70 million rows in all.